# xDebug remote_connect_back not working for AWS EC2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, xdebug

The EC2 instance (with Ubuntu 12.04) has setup of **Apache 2.4.6** and **Php 5.5.6 + xDebug 2.2.2**. Apache and PHP were built using make. Everything is working fine, except for xDebug.

Contents of log file and php.ini

**php.ini**

```
    zend_extension="/opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.remote_mode=req
    xdebug.idekey=xdebug
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
    xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug_remote_log.log"
    xdebug.extended_info=1
```

**/tmp/xdebug_remote_log.log**

```
    Log opened at 2013-11-29 13:18:35
    I: Checking remote connect back address.
    I: Remote address found, connecting to 117.197.126.1:9000.
    E: Could not connect to client. :-(
    Log closed at 2013-11-29 13:18:36
```

I've exactly the same setup of Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 5.5.6 on a **local CentOS 6.3 machine, that works just fine**.

Comment: Do you have your port 9000 open for connect from the internet?

Comment: Php 5.5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04? You did your raped your system that much? Ubuntu packagers did think before they choosen 5.3 for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Maerlyn Yes, port 9000 is open for Internet.

Comment: Have you allready tried a `telnet 117.197.126.1 9000`on the EC2 machine? Maybe it is a firewall issue on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my DLink Router preventing any inbound connection requests.

Setting up **port-forwarding** resolved this.

**Note :** Only set desired port(s) for inbound connections.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on How you connect to the EC2 instance, you can have to open a Tunnel between your Computer and the EC2. This is specially the case if you can't redirect the port 9000 from the EC2 to your computer at work or at home (for any reason, like security, unable to open a port in the router etc... )

From your computer (OSX or Linux), open the SSH Tunnel:

```
ssh -N -R 9000:localhost:9000 ubuntu@domain_or_ip
```

Assuming you've already installed php5-xdebug, add these lines at the end of your php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

And restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

The port 9000 should be successfully redirected to netbeans (if you use Netbeans) or your editor which supports xdebug

Hope this can help somebody

Comment: Forgive my dumb question, but which php.ini I have to edit? EC2's or local? And where should I point my debugger tool (eclipse btw) to? Local or Remote?

Comment: @pojda I think you need php.ini on remote server

Comment: Denis could you describe how open SSH tunnel? What I need to do to use it?

Comment: It is already written in my answer:
ssh -N -R 9000:localhost:9000 ubuntu@domain_or_ip

. Depending how the EC2 is setup you probably need the -i option with the your ssh key:

ssh -N -R 9000:localhost:9000 -i /where/you/key/is ubuntu@domain_or_ip - Are you using windows?
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel

Otherwise you can probably use "bash on ubuntu on windows" which you can now enable in WIndows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to restart:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```